# Recursive SQL retrieve all levels

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I am unable to retrieve the desired result my query when using Oracle's recursive approach:

**Foo**

```
ID1     ID2
1       2
1       3
4       2
4       3
4       5
```

Query:

```
select sys_connect_by_path(id2,' -> ')
FROM Foo
  START WITH id1 = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id1 = id2
ORDER BY 1;
```

Outputs only level 1 hierarchy (2,3). I want it to detect the tree ( 1 -> (2,3) -> 4 -> 5 ), such that selecting distinct **ID2** yields (2,3,5). Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you're expecting to see? Your tree only has a max level of 1 in it. In your query, you're starting with ID1=1, and in your data there's no way to get from there to ID2=5. You'd need a row in your data with ID1=2, ID2=5. Or ID1=1, ID2=4. Or you could get rid of the `start with id1=1` to show your whole tree - but there's still only 1 level, so the `connect by` does nothing.

Comment: Please post the expected output of the query. You may also want to use `START WITH id1 in ( 1,4)` i.e. start with all ID1's that has no parent - this will end in selecting all rows of the table.

Comment: `select distinct id2` does yield the records 2,3,5. What is the problem?

Comment: Fundamentally, I need to input (x) and output all nodes that (at some level) interrelate. In R, I can do this by creating a graph view of the Foo table and creating a matrix using edge-lists. 

I may be approaching this wrong and open to options. A cluster of all interrelations is also a valid output. I.E.:

1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5
1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 11.2 or above, a CTE (Common Table Expression) is preferred over using Oracle's *CONNECT BY* statement.

```
WITH
    aset -- Create pseudo table with ID2 as ID1 and vice versa
    AS
        (SELECT id1, id2
           FROM (SELECT id1, id2
                   FROM foo
                 UNION
                 SELECT id2, id1
                   FROM foo)
          WHERE id1 < id2),
    bset (id1, id2) -- Extract hierarchy from pseudo table
    AS
        (SELECT id1, id2
           FROM aset
          WHERE id1 = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT aset.id1, aset.id2
           FROM bset INNER JOIN aset ON bset.id2 = aset.id1
          WHERE bset.id1 <> aset.id2)
  SELECT DISTINCT bset.id2  -- Only keep values that were originally ID2
    FROM bset INNER JOIN foo ON bset.id2 = foo.id2
ORDER BY id2;
```

Here is the same thing using *CONNECT BY*

```
WITH
    aset
    -- Create pseudo table with ID2 as ID1 and vice versa
    AS
        (SELECT id1, id2
           FROM (SELECT id1, id2
                   FROM foo
                 UNION
                 SELECT id2, id1
                   FROM foo)
          WHERE id1 < id2),
    bset
    -- Extract hierarchy from pseudo table
    AS
        (    SELECT id2
               FROM aset
         START WITH id1 = 1
         CONNECT BY PRIOR id2 = id1)
  SELECT DISTINCT bset.id2
    -- Only keep values that were originally ID2
    FROM bset INNER JOIN foo ON bset.id2 = foo.id2
ORDER BY id2
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. Any suggestions to have 'whiere id1 = 2' not output 5? Currently it will due to the reverse UNION in aset table. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, is the technique used for the virtual table 'aset' (the reverse-union) a known pattern/concept that I can read about somewhere? Thanks Brian.

Comment: I wrote this routine to the data that you provided. I believe your data is incorrect, but I adapted to it anyway to get your desired result. As @kfinity stated, you should have additional records with of (id1,id2) (2, 4) (3,4) to reflect the connections from 2 to 4 and 3 to 4. Your desired outcome from the data you provided has ID2 values linking back to ID1 via other values in ID2, hence my reverse-union. This is not the normal relationship for a hierarchical table.

Comment: As for eliminating results from 2, since it isn't in ID1, simply change the CTE above the union to `SELECT id1, id2
 FROM aset inner join foo on aset.id1 = foo.id1
 WHERE id1 = 2`
This will eliminate results for anything that doesn't have an ID1 value.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now that the nature of my data model does not fit under relational, nor SQL's-graph variation. It is however, valid in scope of the application that is generating this model. Your solution helped me see the bigger picture. The only thing I am a little unclear about is why it is only a 1-level tree. If i draw a tree (1) --> (2,3) ---> (4) ---> (5). Intuitively, this is 3 levels to me (and 0 is parent). Do you mean in strict relational terms it is only a 1 level tree B/C my model implies the relation but does not contain a row for id1:2, id2:4?

Comment: Try naming your columns parent and child. Once you do that you can see that  2 and 3 have no children and that your data model is flawed. Your data model is saying "I have a relationship, it may be parent child or it may be child parent," In other words, you have assigned two distinct meanings to the columns, a no-no in the relational model where every column has one and only one meaning.